# robot_localization fails due to transform warnings

Tags: navigation, gps, transforms, tf2, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to use the robot_localization package for sensor fusion. I've got three sensors: IMU, odometry and GPS.
I was first trying to work with the configuration I've found here:

[link to other question](http://answers.ros.org/question/215904/robot_localization-failed-to-transform-warning/?comment=252296#post-id-252296)

I downloaded the files from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzZeubT6hZReNGthQ2NRRjBaVjQ/view)

Unfortunately if I execute the launch file I first got these errors:

```
[ WARN] [1484753899.869852461, 1440023596.548412649]: Could not obtain transform from /gps to base_footprint. Error was Invalid argument "/gps" passed to lookupTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like:
```

As suggested from @tom-moore in an [answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/215904/robot_localization-failed-to-transform-warning/?comment=252296#post-id-252296) I changed the frame_id from /gps to gps

But just the error message changed:

```
[ WARN] [1484754315.316805588, 1440023620.550000278]: Could not obtain transform from gps to base_footprint. Error was "gps" passed to lookupTransform argument source_frame does not exist.
```

EDIT 1:
I can reproduce the error on different computers. I was setting up ubuntu with a clean ros installation without any success. As a result I get the same errors.

EDIT 2:
I've uploaded my current configuration [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/erl24w9eytfayup/test_sensorfusion_notWorking.zip?dl=0) ( It contains the launch File and a sample of the recorded data)

It has three topics: imu/data, fix and odom
the odom first received odom message is not at position (0,0) in the odom frame ( this was due to the fact that I was driving around with the robot first and I started recording after that)

Transformations:
The GPS-antenna was mounted at the center of the robot, so I think the transformation should be alright..

I hope someone can help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252309/robot_localization-fails-due-to-transform-warnings/) by [modotz](https://answers.ros.org/users/29096/modotz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-01-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2017-01-19**:
Do you have a URDF or some other means of publishing the transform between the two frames? What is the output of `rosrun tf tf_echo gps base_footprint`?

**Comment by [modotz](https://answers.ros.org/users/29096/modotz/) on 2017-01-23**:
thanks for this tip. the transform was missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, I would advise that you [review](http://wiki.ros.org/tf) the `tf` library. The node is telling you that there is no transform defined from your robot's `base_footprint` frame to its `gps` frame. In other words, in order for `navsat_transform_node` to know how to integrate your GPS data, it needs to know where on your robot the GPS itself is mounted. Imagine a robot with a GPS that is mounted on a long arm that sticks out in front of the robot. Since we want to know the pose of the robot's center (in this case, the *base_footprint* frame), we need to know what that offset (transform) is.

In this case, you need to use either (a) the `robot_state_publisher` or (b) a `static_transform_publisher` to define and broadcast a transform from your *base_footprint* frame to your *gps* frame.

**RESPONSE TO EDIT 2**:

Just looking at the launch file, I can see a couple issues:

1. Both your EKFs need to have the same `base_link_frame` frame_id. For your `ekf_odom` instance, you have it set to *base_footprint*, and for the `ekf_map` instance, you have it set to *base_link*.
2. Once you fix (1), make sure your `base_to_realsense` static transform uses the same child frame_id that you use for the `base_link_frame` in the EKF instances.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2017-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [modotz](https://answers.ros.org/users/29096/modotz/) on 2017-01-23**:
Thanks!. I added a `static_transform_publisher` which broadcasts the transformation.
Although I don't get any errors anymore the result is confusing. I was driving with my robot in one direction made a curve around a tree and then returned to the start position. (1)

**Comment by [modotz](https://answers.ros.org/users/29096/modotz/) on 2017-01-23**:
(1) continued. Could you take a look over my [launch files](https://www.dropbox.com/s/erl24w9eytfayup/test_sensorfusion_notWorking.zip?dl=0)?

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2017-01-26**:
Can you please edit the question by posting your launch files and sample input messages?

**Comment by [modotz](https://answers.ros.org/users/29096/modotz/) on 2017-01-26**:
Edited Question.